# Regular Expression - 2 letters and 2 numbers in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to develop a regular expression to validate a string that comes to me like: "TE33" or "FR56" or any sequence respecting 2 letters and 2 numbers.

The first 2 characters must be alphabetic and 2 last caracters must be numbers.

I tried many combinations and I didn't have success. Last one I tried:

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(myString, "^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{2}")){
}
```

Comment: I always sort these out on a regex testing website then go into vs.net with something that I know works from interactive testing.

Comment: A good testing website will help you with these, such as http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: Works fine for me. What exactly do your incoming strings look like? Are you trying to match part of a string or are those 4 characters the whole string?

Comment: Another testing site I always use is http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx One nice aspect is that it's actually the .NET flavor of Regex

Comment: What is wrong? It works for me.

Comment: @Dan-SP, Does you string also have whitespaces around the value? Consider doing `myString.Trim()` before match then...

Comment: @MattBurland - Regex Hero is using .NET regular expressions as well.

Comment: @SteveWortham: Yeah, I noticed that. But the link I gave doesn't try and sell you something.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You're missing an ending anchor.

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(myString, "^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{2}\z")) {
    // ...
}
```

[Here's a demo.](http://ideone.com/Gyeiu)

---

EDIT: If you can have anything between an initial 2 letters and a final 2 numbers:

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(myString, @"^[A-Za-z]{2}.*\d{2}\z")) {
    // ...
}
```

[Here's a demo.](http://ideone.com/ePv3d)

Comment: This shouldn't matter unless you really need to reject any strings that are longer than expected.

Comment: This also matches with out the anchor at the end, something else might be the matter.   http://ideone.com/wZk6B

Comment: @WilliamDwyer: Sorry, I chose some bad test cases. Without the anchor, it will fail for strings like `AB12 I am invalid`. But I might have misunderstood the question, so I added an alternative.

Comment: -1, would allow a `\n` at the end of string. Use `\z` instead.

Answer (score 8):

This should get you for starting with two letters and ending with two numbers.

```
[A-Za-z]{2}(.*)[0-9]{2}
```

If you know it will always be just two and two you can

```
[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{2}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun, here's a non-regex (more readable/maintainable for simpletons like me) solution:

```
string myString = "AB12";

if( Char.IsLetter(myString, 0) && 
    Char.IsLetter(myString, 1) && 
    Char.IsNumber(myString, 2) &&
    Char.IsNumber(myString, 3)) {
    // First two are letters, second two are numbers
}
else {
    // Validation failed
}
```

**EDIT**

It seems that I've misunderstood the requirements. The code below will ensure that the first two characters and last two characters of a string validate (so long as the length of the string is > 3)

```
string myString = "AB12";

if(myString.Length > 3) {    
    if( Char.IsLetter(myString, 0) && 
        Char.IsLetter(myString, 1) && 
        Char.IsNumber(myString, (myString.Length - 2)) &&
        Char.IsNumber(myString, (myString.Length - 1))) {
        // First two are letters, second two are numbers
      }
      else {
        // Validation failed
    }
}
else {
   // Validation failed
}
```

Comment: Note that IsLetter is **much** broader than A-Z. You can also use the same kind check for digits.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, `A-Z` noted. I'd never used `Char.IsNumber` before. Thanks for the heads up (updated code)!

Comment: @JamesHill, that's the problem with OPs expression... See the top voted answer. `validate a string that comes to me like: "TE33" or "FR56" or any sequence respecting 2 letters and 2 numbers`, how does `TE3345FAIL` fit in that?